# List of recently changed files for a directory and all subdirectories

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, filesystems

In Linux I know this command to find and list the latest modified files in a directory with all its subdirectories.

```
find /var/www/ -type f -exec stat --format '%Y :%y %n' {} \; | sort -nr | cut -d: -f2- | head
```

Is there a Windows CLI equivalent?

Comment: are you looking for only modified files?  Or are you looking at all files?

Comment: I'm sure PowerShell can do this *far* more easily than batch, but if you absolutely *must* use the latter... Try `dir /a-d /o-d /tw /s` (show files only, order by date descending, use last write time for sorting, recurse into subdirs). However this will list all files. To limit the list to n latest modified files only, use *dbenham*'s brilliant solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11934361).

Comment: A couple of comments on the Linux command: (1) Instead of `-exec`, you might want to consider `xargs`.  (2) If you, as you say, want to sort an entire directory (sub)tree by modification date (and then look at the newest _N_), then what you have is reasonable.  But if you can get the information you need by finding all files modified in the last _N_ days, look at `find … -mtime …`.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, you can also look into `forfiles /s /d +<date>`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### PowerShell 2.0

Latest 10 changed files

```
Dir C:\folder -r | ? {! $_.PSIsContainer} | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 10
```

Changed files since given date

```
Dir C:\folder -r | ? {! $_.PSIsContainer -AND $_.lastwritetime -ge '04/18/14'}
```

---

Read more on http://ss64.com/ps/

Comment: If you just want to show the directories with modified files, do this. 

Dir d:\sftp -r | ? {! $_.PSIsContainer -AND $_.lastwritetime -ge '05/25/2018'} |findstr Directory

Answer (score 0):

```
dir c:\windows\ /aa /s /O-D
```

Lists all the files with the archive attribute set (modified) in the c:\windows folder and all its subfolders by date (newest first)

Edit:  This method will only work if you clear the archive bits at some point or the list will just grow and grow.

Comment: What does the Archive attribute have to do with recently changed files?

Comment: ***Everything***.  Any file that gets changed gets the archive attribute set by the OS.  Thats how backup programs know that a file has changed and needs to be backed up.

Comment: Your edit is extremely important. Files with +A already will see no change. Why not find some way to do this based on Date Modified?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MT Directory Changes Watcher. May be it is right for your needs.

> Program watches for file changes in particular directory (Watch
>   directory) and then copies changed files to another folder (Mirror
>   directory) saving directory structure. This can be very useful when
>   you have local copy of remote site and want to upload only files,
>   changed locally after last upload.

http://mito-team.com/projects/dcw